# Rmysql connection failing

Tags: r, rmysql

The sysadmin just made SSL connection compulsory and since then I'm not able to access the mysql db anymore from R (even if I'm able to access it through Workbench) using the package RMysql. I tried multiple options without success and here is the error I get in R Studio:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'blabla'@'host.blablabla' (using password: YES)
```

I read that I should modify my cnf file, but as I could not find it I created one in the /etc folder and still did not work. Should I save it somewhere else? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the RMySql version that is on GitHub at the moment.